# How can i connect a Javascript client to a Python-SocketIO server?

Tags: javascript, python, django, socket.io

I'm just getting started to Python-SocketIO, i created an example server, it looks like this:

```
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()

app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

@sio.on('msg')
def message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

Then, i have an **HTML** file which is running on a Django application, i would like to connect that client to my Python-SocketIO server:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

socket = io.connect('');

socket.on('connect',function() {
  console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
});

socket.on('msg',function(data) {
  console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
});

socket.on('disconnect',function() {
  console.log('The client has disconnected!');
});

// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function send(message) {
  socket.send('msg',message);
};

</script>
```

The problem is that, on my client side, i keep getting the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5eSEa2' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5eSEa2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

My Django server is running `on http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. Can anyone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the CORS header on your server:

```
sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579110/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-error-in-a-python-socket-io-server))